# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ... (using password: YES)

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to install magento 2.1 on the server and in the second step it presents this error:
[image]

The data I am putting in is correct, but from this error. When I go through the command line, give me this information:
[image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user "root" doesn't have permission to access your database from that IP. I recommend creating a user specifically for Magento.

Login to your mysql account or ask Linode support to reset your mysql root password to something you can access.

`$ mysql -u root -h 139.162.240.116 -p`

Enter the password for your root user provided by Linode. Once logged in you'll see the mysql> prompt.

`mysql> create database magento;`

`mysql> create user magento;`

Based on your screen cap, I'd set your magento user up this way:

`mysql> grant all on magento.* to 'magento'@'li1525-116.members.linode.com' identified by 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE';`

(replace YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE with a more complex password.)

`mysql> flush privileges;`

`mysql> quit`

You should now be able to use the following credentials when setting up Magento:

```
Database Server Host: 139.162.240.116
Database Server Username: magento
Database Server Password: YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE (whatever you set this to)
Database Name: magento
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using xampp in windows and tried installing magento 2.4 and faced the same error.

I noticed that the mysql is running in a different port (3307).

So in the magento install command I gave

**--db-host=”localhost:3307”**

Then it started working !

Hope this helps someone facing the same issue !